# SELECT query having 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

hy all,
i have 3 tables in which i use the following query:

```
$getquery = mysql_query("SELECT u_fullname , p_name, grade FROM description, users, projects WHERE description.user_id = users.u_id AND description.project_id = projects.p_id GROUP BY u_fullname, p_name, grade LIMIT $start, $per_page");
```

Everything works well, except the fact that i always have extra numbers in the pagination containing empty results.
Anyone could point out if the problem is in the query ? or it might be something else???

In case inner join was the solution , how can i use my query through it??

Comment: Have you tried the query without using limit??

Comment: im using the limit for pagination

Comment: "In case inner join was the solution" It is the solution  - You should a least try it yourself!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

> ```
> $getquery = mysql_query(
>          "SELECT u.u_fullname , p.p_name, d.grade, SUM(d.total_hours) ".
>          "FROM users u ".
>          "INNER JOIN description d ON d.user_id = u.u_id ".
>          "LEFT JOIN projects p ON d.project_id = p.p_id ".
>          "GROUP BY u.u_fullname, p.p_name, d.grade ".
>          "LIMIT $start, $per_page");
> ```

Comment: grade is a column in table description. i tried your query and it worked similarly as mine.i get the right results but in pagination i still have pages of empty results

Comment: I'm update answer. why are you grouping results? Try without GROUP section

Comment: im using group by because i also want to show results of SUM(total_hours) where total_hours is taken from table desciption...i forgot to put it in the query

Comment: wh ni removed the SUM(total_hours) and group by it worked, like you said

Comment: `total_hours` is the field of `description`? The problem still actual?

Comment: it works in case i remove group by and SUM(total_hours), but SUM(total_hours) doesnt work if i dont put GROUP BY and therefore i get back to the main problem

Comment: this query displayed the only u_fullname from table users

Comment: `always have extra numbers in the pagination containing empty results` - how much results without pagination what is `$per_page` value? I'm little update query...

Comment: $per_page is how many results i want to show per page.This query also diplays extra pages that are empty

Comment: Yes, I'm understand. I think that all results is 10 items and you have  $per_page=10. Than in second page (by using `LIMIT 11,10`) will be an empty. That's why I ask you how many all resulted items and is this number bigger than your $per_page

Comment: the number is not bigger than $per_page. $per_page = 6; $start  = 0; in the result, page 1 shows 6 elements, page 2 and 3 as well and then starting page 4 till page 7, i have empty elements.how can i remove those added pages?